# Total of all subtotals from a single function

Tags: javascript, function

i have a function which returns the subtotal of an item (qty * price) for each item in the cart, however i am struggling to add all of the subtotals to make one final total.

My subtotals are calculated from a HTML input value which is set to a + and - button

```
<div class="quantity">
  <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '-');" class="minus-btn">
    <img src="/img/shop/minus-btn.png" alt="#">
  </button>

  <input id="valueTest1" onchange="calculateSubTotal(this);" type="text" value="0" data-price="10.99">

  <button onclick="Input_ChangeValue(this, '+');" class="plus-btn" >
    <img src="/img/shop/plus-btn.png" alt="#">
  </button>
</div>
```

and then output to the subtotal div `<div id="itemTotal1" class="subtotal-price">£0.00</div>`

However when i try to push the subtotal values of the separate items to an array the function is only seeing the last item incremented, would i be better trying some kind of for loop here?

My goal is to get .subtotal-prices to output to

```
<div class="summary-total">
  <div class="total-title">Total</div>
  <div class="total-value final-value" data-price="0" id="basket-total">£0.00</div>
</div>
```

i will post a working snippet of my code in case i have made a mistake in my function https://jsbin.com/dubociw/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a loop to look for all `.subtotal-price` items and then sum them up to get total.

```
    const subtotals = document.querySelectorAll(".subtotal-price");
    let total = 0;
    subtotals.forEach(subtotalItem => {
       const priceString = subtotalItem.innerText.replace("£", "");
       total += parseFloat(priceString);
    });
    const basketTotal = document.querySelector("#basket-total");
    basketTotal.innerHTML = total;
```

Or another way is store an array of products in cart include quantity and price (and product id if needed). Then manipulate the array on change quantity and sum the total price. With this way, you can use the array to display product/price/quantity/subtotal anywhere, such as the sub total in basket summary.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what i was looking for, i think i need to study the .forEach as i didn't even think of that

Comment: You can use any kind of loop function/statement in JS beside `forEach`